# Exporting perfmon counters via SNMP

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, monitoring, snmp

I've got perfmon displaying the current number of ASP.NET requests on a Windows 2008 server, all good there.

I've enabled the SNMP service and I can perform an snmpwalk (Linux command to browse the snmp MIBs) on the machine.

I'm now looking to export the perfmon data so I can read this via SNMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Performance Monitor counters are available through SNMP out of the box. There are some add-ons available that will add that functionality though.

A paid version: [SNMP Informant](http://www.snmp-informant.com/)

and a free one: [SNMP Tools](http://erwan.l.free.fr/snmptools/)

Comment: snmptools did the job perfectly. I couldn't export the native counters, but I used the "exec" with the included perf32.exe to print out the appropiate counters.

For anyone interested also, the counter I've started with is \Web Service(_Total)\Total Connection Attempts (all instances)

Answer (score 2):

Install snmptools and add counters to the counters.ini file.Perfmon counters can be obtained using "Typeperf -qx" command.
Example below shows counter.ini file with few general counters.

the base OID is 1.3.6.1.4.1.15

```
;% Processor Time - 2.1.x


[1.3.6.1.4.1.15.2.1.1]

counter=Processor\% Processor Time\_Total

;Memory - 5.1.x


[1.3.6.1.4.1.15.5.1.1] 

counter=Memory\Available Bytes

;Paging File - 6.1.x


[1.3.6.1.4.1.15.6.1.1]
counter=Paging File(_Total)\% Usage

[1.3.6.1.4.1.15.6.1.2]
counter=Paging File(_Total)\% Usage Peak
```

Restart SNMP, check returned values:
    snmpget -v2c -c public hostname 1.3.6.1.4.1.15.5.1.1
    iso.3.6.1.4.1.15.5.1.1 = STRING: "2235023360"

This counter returns available memory in Bytes.